# how to to insert Static drop down value in to database or a single table

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, insert

I have a drop down list, in this list have a many list item which is static like

```
<asp:dropdownlist id = "abc" runat ="server">
<ListItem>1</ListItem>
<ListItem>2</ListItem>
<ListItem>3</ListItem>
<ListItem>4</ListItem>
 .....   
 .....    
 .....  
<ListItem>200</ListItem>         
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

I want to insert all the drop down list values in to data-base or a single table.

I created a test page and tried applying looping on load but it didn't work.

so any body can suggest me any way for inserting all values it to data base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your aspx the items need to be asp:ListItems

```
<asp:DropDownList id="abc" runat ="server">
  <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>200</asp:ListItem>         
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And then in the page load (where SqlInsert is your method to do the database inserts).

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in abc.Items)
        {
            SqlInsert(item.Value, item.Text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the list size to a variable, then loop through the list and assign as needed. Ex:

```
    Dim listSize as Integer = abc.Items.Count
    For i as Integer = 0 to listSize
         'Do code here with items
          'abc.Items.Item(i) = ??
    Next
```